# CTE vs TVF Performance

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

Which performs better: common table expressions or table value functions?  Im designing a process that I could use either and am unable to find any real data either way.  Whatever route I choose would be executed via a SP and the data would ultimately update a table connected through a linked server (unfortunately there is no way around this).  Insights appreciated.

Comment: If you need to pass in a table structure as an input then go with TVF else within SP you can use CTE. Why are you considering TVF against CTE?

Comment: This isn't really a performance question. You are comparing tuna fish and watermelons. A cte is an inline view that can be used by the next query only. A TVF is a complete unit of work that can function on it's own, unlike a cte. They both have their place and when used correctly are incredibly powerful tools.

Comment: After closer review I totally agree with you @SeanLange.  If you add this as an answer I will mark it so you get some cred for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a performance question. You are comparing tuna fish and watermelons. A cte is an inline view that can be used by the next query only. A TVF is a complete unit of work that can function on it's own, unlike a cte. They both have their place and when used correctly are incredibly powerful tools.